# ffmpeg - how to remove audio from video in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, audio, video, ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i input_file.mp4 -an -vcodec copy output_file.mp4
```

How can I change it to something like this below?

```
FFMpeg::fromDisk('local')
->open($filePath.$fileName)
->export()
->toDisk('local')
->inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('libmp3lame', 'libx264'))
->save($converted);
```

Comment: you have completely changed the question, but the title is still "how to remove audio from video". This is how to use FFMpeg library (https://github.com/pascalbaljetmedia/laravel-ffmpeg) I suggested to your original question. This question should be asked on the github issues or just read the docs

Comment: I didn't change because I want to remove audio from video! and I can't understand that link mentioned! just tell me how I can remove audio from video!

Answer (score 1):

**1. Which one is better?**
Too subjective, depends on your requirements. I'd go with .mp4 as support is much better across most (modern) browsers

```
-i is the input file e.g. input_file.mp4
-an Disable audio recording.
-c is codec. basically -c copy says copy without reencoding
copy ... well, copies to output file e.g. output_file.mp4
-vcodec sets the vide encoder.
```

If used together with -vcodec copy, it will affect the aspect ratio stored at container level, but not the aspect ratio stored in encoded frames, if it exists.

**2. How to use in Laravel**
A few options:

I'd prob check out this library first: https://github.com/pascalbaljetmedia/laravel-ffmpeg

or if you want to roll your own...

Laravel is forked from Symfony so you can use the built in Process runner found here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

$cmd = 'ffmpeg -i input_file.mp4 -an -vcodec copy output_file.mp4';
$process = new Process($cmd);
$process->run();

// executes after the command finishes
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}

echo $process->getOutput();
```

Comment: I didn't get my answer. How can I change it to FFMpeg standard? like this: FFMpeg::fromDisk('local')->open($filePath.$fileName)->export()->toDisk('local')->inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('libmp3lame', 'libx264'))->save($converted);

Comment: That also is a different question and not asked. Thats saving the file. You will have a file "output_file.mp4", so maybe google how to save this using laravel or ask another question